# How to power CCFLs from backlight using original inverters (from a disasembled LCD screen)

Tags: lcd, ccfl

I've search the net and dealers for specs of these inverters, no chance!

I'd like to make somme discreet lightings with the CCFLs, as the screen was disasembled in a hurry, without noting the connections, I can't figure out the power and the wireing to use.

As there were 18 CCFL and 2 inverters in this screen, it's easy to figure out that each inverter can power 9 tubes, but I'm stuck there.

Must I use all tube or the power will adapt to 3, 4 or 10?

Thanks for your time!

[image: Inverters KLS-EE26-S(M)]
[image: LG CCFL]

Comment: You can see some of the conenctions labelled on the PCB.  Drive voltage is typically 12V or the external PSU voltage directly if it was not supplied by the logic board SMPSU.  There is usually a input to switch the driver on that may be 0V or 5V and floating off.  There may be a voltage or PWM input to adjust the tube brightness.

Answer (score 1):

As a general guidelines, most CCFL drivers are fairly adaptive. You can lower the number of tubes without issue. You could increase it by one without much issue. Whether your invertor can do so depends on its specs, but as a one off project I would risk it.

Comment: Thank you! That will be usefull, but do you know how to make the connections?

Comment: A CCFL inverter is just a low voltage to high voltage transformer of a certain frequency. They are normally constant voltage regulators. So driving less tubes of a fixed length is not a problem.

Comment: The connections would be the same as normal. The tube connectors should only fit one way